# why is function executing twice?

Tags: python

Am experiencing a bizarre problem with my python script the file is being red twice.

Script:

```
import platform as serverPlatform


class platform:

  @staticmethod
  def kernel():
    return serverPlatform.release()

  @staticmethod
  def cpu():
    with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as f:
        print("x")
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                if line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[0].startswith('model name'):
                    model_name = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[1]

print platform.cpu()
```

The code above prints "x" twice:

```
[root@localhost lib]# python platform.py
x
x
```

However if i remove the class and run the code found inside the `cpu()` method directly it prints me "x" only once.(python script without the class)

```
with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as f:
    print("x")
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            if line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[0].startswith('model name'):
                model_name = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[1]
```

What am I doing wrong in my initial script and why is it printing me "x" twice? Thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

Ok I realised my mistake as silly as it may sound I imported the module platform in a script containing the custom class names platform. So i changed the name of the class from **platform** to **platforms**

```
import platform as serverPlatform


class platforms:

  @staticmethod
  def kernel():
    return serverPlatform.release()

  @staticmethod
  def cpu():
    with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as f:
        print("x")
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                if line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[0].startswith('model name'):
                    model_name = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[1]

print platforms.cpu()
```

Comment: When I run the script code, it only prints x once for me. Is there any other part of the script file that's missing?

Comment: Is this the entirety of your script? Perhaps you left out something important when you posted it here, such as an `import platform` line you're not showing us.

Comment: indeed i forgot the `import platform as serverPlatform` in the copy paste process. If i comment the import the script works fine. why is it so?

Comment: ` import platform as serverPlatform` will import the moule/script, while importing it will execute the statements in it. So it wil execute `platform.cpu()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while importing python scripts, it will execute all the statements, like function declaration, class declaration and executable statements (like print). So when you import flatform it will execute `flatform.cpu()` once. and one more call from the file in which you imported.